# Why use the double cover instead of the universal cover of $SO(2)$?

Tags: quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory, topology

In QM, we are generally looking for projective representations of the underlying symmetry group (because of Wigner's theorem). So generally, we should be looking for representations of central extensions of the universal covering group, according to Bargmann. In the case of $SO(n)$ with $n>2$, the universal covering groups happen to coincide with the double coverings. However, for $SO(2)$, this is not the case. Why are we still interested only in the double cover in the case of $SO(2)$ and not in its universal cover?

**EDIT:** To be more specific, let me restrict the question to the case of the $\mathrm{Spin}(2)$ group: Why is this group defined this way and not as the universal cover of $SO(2)$? Is there any physical reason to consider the double cover instead of the universal cover? It seems like this definition potentially excludes interesting physics from consideration.

Comment: Can you quote Bargmann's theorem exactly? There is always "universal cover" in it. "Double cover" is only by a coincidence for the rotation+Lorentz group in (1+)3 spatial dimensions. As you say, for SO(2), there is no double cover, but an infinite cover.

Comment: Bargmanns theorem says that the projective representations are in one-to-one correspondence with representations of the central extensions of the universal cover. There is still a double cover for $SO(2)$ (the $Spin(2)$ group), but the double cover doesn't coincide with the universal cover in this case.

Comment: To rephrase my question: Why is a spin structure on a manifold defined in terms of double covers? Why do we only consider the double cover of $SE(2)$ (little group for massless particles) when looking for physically relevant representations of the Poincare group? Shouldn't we be looking at universal covers in all these cases?

Comment: Hi Nullstein. Who are we?

Comment: @Qmechanic For example in the Wikipedia articles on [Spin structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure) or [Wigner classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_classification). I have also seen it in several textbooks, but I can't look it up right now. Generally, $Spin(n)$ seems to be defined as the double cover of $SO(n)$ and not the universal cover, also for $n=2$.

Comment: i was studying the same thing preparing my qft 1 exam in Wigner classification. I also find it restrictive to consider only the double cover, or at least i see no other reason than experimental evidence to do it. if im not mistaken one could make a triple cover of SO(2) corresponding to helicity of 1/3 and so on and i dont see a reason but experimental evidence or perhaps some analogy with the massive case where the spin group is the universal cover

Comment: Perhaps its merely a decision of naming convention. The spin group is always the double cover. Thus if the double cover isnt also the universal cover, you'd want to call whatever $n$-cover something else besides the spin group.

Comment: @Craig The question is not about a naming convention. I know that the spin group is defined to be the double cover. I'm asking why people consider the double cover in the first place. Why wasn't the spin group defined to be the universal cover? It appears to be the physically more relevant choice.

Comment: Is there an example of a group which has a double cover that is not its universal cover, and also is not its own double cover? I think that would make for the most interesting formulation this question. I think you may also be interested in anyons, if you have not yet run across them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon

Comment: @Craig Yes, in 2 dimensions. Anyons are the very reason for why I'm asking this question, because they are described by the universal cover, which is bigger than the Spin group.