# What is the motivation for the $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ group to be the double cover of $SO(n)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, topology

The $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ group is defined to be the double cover of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$. In the case of $n > 2$, this agrees with the universal cover. However, for $n=2$, the physically relevant group should be the universal covering group of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ rather than $\mathrm{Spin}(2)$. So why do we define it this way and in what cases is $\mathrm{Spin}(2)$ ever useful? Why is it worth to be considered?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/639162/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic I figured that my previous question might not have been specific enough, so I restricted this question to the example of the spin groups.

Comment: @NDewolf No, this was my previous, less specific question, but it didn't receive any answers.

Comment: A problem with your question seems to be that you ask for general $n$ but it is really only about the specific case $n=2$. Consider to concentrate on that. Also consider to edit and improve a post rather than open new threads.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, it's essentially only about $n=2$, but maybe there is a deeper reason for why the double cover is physically interesting and it only coincides with the universal cover.

Comment: @Qmechanic The notice at the top says: "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." Would a new question remain open if I restrict it to $n=2$?

Comment: Oh, this is [this issue](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13577/2451) currently under review. No, it will likely get closed. Edit instead.

Comment: Alright, I have edited my original question. Indeed, this makes more sense.